# How to check if two pandas dataframes have same values and concatenate those rows?

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I got a DF called "df" with 4 numerical columns [frame,id,x,y]
I made a loop that creates two dataframes called df1 and df2. Both df1 and df2 are subseted of the original dataframe.

What I want to do (and I am not understanding how to do it) is this: I want to CHECK if df1 and df2 have same VALUES in the column called "id". If they do, I want to concatenate those rows of df2 (that have the same id values) to df1.

For example: if df1 has rows with different id values (1,6,4,8) and df2 has this id values (12,7,8,10). I want to concatenate df2 rows that have the id value=8 to df1. That is all I need

This is my code:

```
for i in range(0,max(df['frame']),30):
 df1=df[df['frame'].between(i, i+30)]
 df2=df[df['frame'].between(i-30, i)]
```

Comment: please provide a reproducible example of input/expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to accomplish what you need.
The simplest one is to get the slice of `df2` that contains the values you need with `.isin()` and concatenate it with `df1` in one line.

`df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2[df2.id.isin(df1.id)]], axis = 0)`

To gain more control and avoid any errors that might stem from updating `df1` and `df2` elsewhere, you may want to take the apart this one-liner.

```
look_for_vals = set(df1['id'].tolist())
# do some stuff
need_ix = df2[df2["id"].isin(look_for_vals )].index
# do more stuff
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2.loc[need_ix,:]], axis=0)
```

Instead of `set()` you may also use `df1['id'].unique()`

Comment: You might also want to apply `.reset_index()` to make sure `df3` has uniquely named rows

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.